# Email is not working in AWS lightsail with plesk controlpanel

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, plesk

I tried with php mail function and the email is not sent. I activated the port 25 in the aws instance network setting but no uses.

Checked the mail settings option in the plesk Controlpanel, I got the following message

`You cannot send emails from Plesk because outbound connections on TCP port 25 is blocked. Check the firewall settings or contact your hosting provider.`

Please give the suggestion, how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to request to amazon  to open that port, by default it is blocked..After request they open it.
Here is the link to request

https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request